# How to add radio buttons with text fields in Flask/WTForms

Tags: python, html, flask, wtforms

I have created a form with Flask and WTForms and I'm trying to make a RadioField with a radio button that says "Others . ." and has a text field beside it so the user can add their custom value to the RadioField.

```py
class PastebinEntry(Form):
    language = SelectField(u'Programming Language', choices=[('cpp', 'C++'), ('py', 'Python'), ('text', 'Plain Text'), ('Others', 'Text Input Here')])
```

Ideally, the radio button would look like this: [Image.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2ScF.png)

Comment: Perhaps I missed it, but there seems to be nothing in the WTForms docs that offers a ready-made solution.  I hope someone proves me wrong on this, because it is not trivial to create it oneself.  The most straightforward way would be to subclass `choices` or a single choice, but that does not seem to be an option.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the RadioField element

```
example = RadioField('Label', choices=[('value','description'),('value_two','whatever')])
```

Comment: I don't think this answers the poster's question, as it does not allow the user to type in an answer.  The poster's screenshot makes it clear what is desired.